# According to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^na_k}{n}=0,\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0,$ then can we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a real sequence with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k}{n}=0,\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0,$$ then can we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0?$$

This simple problem has got on my nerves for two days, I've tried to prove that is ture, however, there's nothing I can get.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn about Tauberian theorems...

Comment: @GEdgar , can you give an explicit direction?

Comment: Instead of $\lim\limits_{n→∞}(a_{n+1}−a_n)=0$, you should use $\lim\limits_{n→∞}n(a_{n+1}−a_n)=0$. Then the expression will be true.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed theorem seems to be false. I think that the series $a_k = \sin( \sqrt{k})$ is a counterexample.

The difference between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ is at most $|\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}|$ because the derivative of sin is between -1 and 1, so it tends to zero.

It's clear that the series $a_n$ does not tend to zero, since its values approach 1 and -1 over and over forever. It remains to show that the mean of $\{a_k\}$ tends to zero. This technical feat is beyond me at the moment, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you modify this to $\sin(\pi\sqrt{k})$, then there is a full wave between every $k=n^2$ and $k=(n+2)^2$. Modify further to have the arguments in that segment equally spaced, then the average should converge to zero. Or alternatively, based on $\sin(\pi\log_2(n)$, $a_{2^n+k}=\sin(k\,2^{1-n}\pi)$ for $k=0,1,\dots,2^{n}-1$.

Comment: I had come up with the way to cope with the limit that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin\sqrt k=0.$$

Comment: Lemma. If the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent, then we have$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=0.$$

Comment: Lemma. Suppose that $f\in C^1[1,+\infty)$ with $$\int_1^\infty|f'(x)|dx<+\infty,$$then the integration $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ has the same convergence as the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n).$ Anyway, thanks for your counterexample.